# История изменения изображения Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Возник вопрос с добавление истории в изменение изображения. Т.е. у меня на форме нарисована картинка, я/пользователь рисую на ней произвольные линии, многоугольники, расставляю точки, закрашиваю области и т.д. Но так как на самом деле эти дополнения к рисунку делаются осознано, и в рисовании их может случиться ошибка, нужно добавить возможность отменить последнее действие, хотя бы.

Логика у меня была примерно как тут: http://rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/backforward.xml разве, что я сделал 1 динамический массив и отмечал текущее положение в нем и двигался вперед назад, а при создании новой ветви писал поверх старой.

Но тут возникла проблема. Я доставал изображение из `TImage`:

```
    inc(current);
    setLength(history, current);
    history[current] := TBitMap.Create;
    history[current] := Image1.Picture.Bitmap;
```

Но тут возникла проблема, при изменении current и перерисовке изображение не менялось. Сохранялось только самое первое, которое я записывал в массив, еще до зарисовывания в `TImage`. Протестировав на новой форме, выставив туда 6 `TImage`, и в каждом прорисовав элемент массива (первые 6), убедился что на первом оригинальное изображение до изменения, и 5 одинаковых, то как `Image1` выглядит сейчас.

Я придумал один способ решить проблему, это сохранять изображение в файл, загружать его потом оттуда в массив. Должно сработать. Но это вроде как костыль.

Comment: Автор, сформулируйте вопрос грамотно, уберите лишнее, укажите в чем конкретно проблема? Может быть все что вы написали про историю к вопросу не относится и проблема только в "при перерисовке изображение не менялось"? Приведите минимальный-воспроизводимый код.

Comment: Да, тут необходим код, которым другие могли бы воспроизвести вашу проблему. А так можно только угадывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сперва объект создается

```
history[current] := TBitMap.Create;
```

потом перезаписывается ссылка на другой объект

```
history[current] := Image1.Picture.Bitmap;
```

так нельзя, Вам нужно написать код вида (для создания копии изображения):

```
history[current].Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
```

Пример использования [тут](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TBitmap_Assign.html)

Вот еще по теме: [Как создать независимую копию TBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281469/how-can-i-create-an-independent-copy-of-a-delphi-tbitmap)

Comment: +1 за Assign при любом рскладе.

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняй изображение в `TMemoryStream` вместо файла.

В таком случае можно ускорить работу с историей, но если некорректно завершить программу - все данные истории будет утеряны. Также есть вероятность того что таких данных будет много и программа будет "жрать" много памяти.

Comment: @androschuk Чтобы добавить свой комментарий к ответу, вы не поверите, есть комментарии. Где вы видели программу, которая сохраняет историю изменений (undo) после закрытия?

Comment: я немного приукрасил ответ, в чем проблема? Ответ начали минусовать сразу же потому что основная проблема не была решена. На счет сохранения истории все в руках автора ;-)